# Cannot delete file because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, file-io

```
for (int i = 0; i < PrefixDistinctCount; i++)
                {
                    string FirstPolicy = "";

                    FirstPolicy = OriginalPics[0].ToString().Substring(26, 7);

                    var SamePoliciesQuery = OriginalPics.Where(x => Path.GetFileName(x).StartsWith(FirstPolicy));

                    foreach (string picture in SamePoliciesQuery)
                    {
                        File.Move(picture, AppVars.ProcessingPolicyImagesDirectory + picture.Substring(26, 12) + ".jpg");
                    }

                    string[] SamePolicyPics = Directory.GetFiles(AppVars.ProcessingPolicyImagesDirectory);
                    GenerateTiffFile(SamePolicyPics);

                    Directory.Delete(AppVars.ProcessingPolicyImagesDirectory, true);
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(AppVars.ProcessingPolicyImagesDirectory);

                    OriginalPics = Directory.GetFiles(SelectedDirectory);
                }
```

Towards the end where it says "Directory.Delete(AppVars.ProcessingPolicyImagesDirectory, true);" i'm getting an error that it's not allowing me to delete the file. I'm GUESSING it's because something in the code is not closing the file or what not. does anyone know what could be the case? or how I would go about using "using" to fix this problem?

IOException was unhandled. The process cannot access the file 'blah blah' because it is being used by another process.

This is the code for GenerateTiffFile -

```
public void GenerateTiffFile(string[] SamePolicyPics)
        {
            ImageCodecInfo info = null;
            foreach (ImageCodecInfo ice in ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders())
                if (ice.MimeType == "image/tiff")
                    info = ice;

            Encoder enc = Encoder.SaveFlag;

            EncoderParameters ep = new EncoderParameters(1);
            ep.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(enc, (long)EncoderValue.MultiFrame);

            Bitmap pages = null;

            int frame = 0;

            foreach (string picture in SamePolicyPics)
            {
                if (frame == 0)
                {
                    pages = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(picture);
                    //pages.Save(picture.Substring(0, picture.Length - 3) + "tiff", info, ep);
                    pages.Save(AppVars.FinalPolicyImagesDirectory + picture.Substring(29, 7)  + ".tiff", info, ep);
                }
                else
                {
                    ep.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(enc, (long)EncoderValue.FrameDimensionPage);
                    Bitmap bm = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(picture);
                    pages.SaveAdd(bm, ep);
                }

                if (frame == SamePolicyPics.Length - 1)
                {
                    ep.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(enc, (long)EncoderValue.Flush);
                    pages.SaveAdd(ep);
                }
                frame++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you by any chance have the picture open? I've done that a few times :)

Comment: haha, nope i don't. made sure right now (even closed the folder) and still the same problem :(

Comment: Please specify the programming language you are using. Is this C#?

Comment: I added the C# tag to your question. This will help people understand your problem better, and it will give you many more views (C# is a very active tag on this site).

Comment: What does GenerateTiffFile(SamePolicyPics) do? It could be related to that.

Comment: Please format your code correctly :'[

Comment: GenerateTiffFile created one .tiff file that is multipaged. See code added to thread.

Comment: I'm not to familiar with Image, but I see it support IDisposable http://www.dotnetperls.com/using so try slapping a using around it.

Comment: can you show me exactly where and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using(Bitmap pages = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(SamePolicyPics[0])){
        int frame = 0;

        foreach (string picture in SamePolicyPics)
        {
            if (frame == 0)
            {
                pages.Save(AppVars.FinalPolicyImagesDirectory + picture.Substring(29, 7)  + ".tiff", info, ep);
            }
            else
            {
                ep.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(enc, (long)EncoderValue.FrameDimensionPage);
                using(Bitmap bm = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(picture)){
                    pages.SaveAdd(bm, ep);
                }
            }

            if (frame == SamePolicyPics.Length - 1)
            {
                ep.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(enc, (long)EncoderValue.Flush);
                pages.SaveAdd(ep);
            }
            frame++;
        }}
```

Comment: still no luck. it still says some other process has that first pic opened :(

Comment: That wasn't easy to find if I say so myself ... :)

Comment: Both bitmaps have to use using. Otherwise some files might remain opened, just like @Joel said, Thanks Joel, very valuable lesson.

Comment: that worked Darek. you the man! thanks everyone else for the help. you guys are great :)

Answer (score 2):

```
Bitmap bm = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(picture);
```

This will keep the file locked until `bm` is disposed, as the [manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5.aspx) says. Wrap it in a `using` block:

```
using (Bitmap bm = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(picture))
{
   // your code
}
```

Comment: So setting bm to null, instead of waiting for GC to collect it, should resolve the issue?

Comment: First thing I would try is wrapping it in using(), the dispose should clean it up without the need to set it to null.

Comment: @user1336632 see edit, but please note some effort from your side (i.e. reading the manual) is expected.

Comment: @Darek setting bm to null would accomplish nothing. All you'd do is break the reference. The actual memory object holding on to the file would still exist until the GC runs.

Comment: @user1336632 setting bm to null would accomplish nothing. All you'd do is break the reference. The actual memory object holding on to the file would still exist until the GC runs.

Comment: using (Bitmap bm = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(picture))
{
   // your code
}

did not work.

Comment: @Joel interesting ... love to learn about intricacies like these ... I personally prefer "usings".

Comment: @user1336632 I assume your code looks like this now (see my new answer)

Answer (score 0):

It'll require some rewriting of your code cause the object will only exist inside the using scope.
But the idea is something like this

```
foreach (string picture in SamePolicyPics)
{
    using (pages = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(picture))
    {
        if (frame == 0)
        {
            pages.Save(AppVars.FinalPolicyImagesDirectory + picture.Substring(29, 7)  + ".tiff", info, ep);
        }
        else
        {
            ep.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(enc, (long)EncoderValue.FrameDimensionPage);
            using (Bitmap bm = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(picture))
            {
              pages.SaveAdd(bm, ep);
            }
        }

        if (frame == SamePolicyPics.Length - 1)
        {
            ep.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(enc, (long)EncoderValue.Flush);
            pages.SaveAdd(ep);
        }
    }
    frame++;
}
```